# removing a value from a linked list/deleting values that were not dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

My textbook has the following code for removing an element from a linked list.

```
void remove(double num)
{
    Node *cur, *prev;
    if(!head){
        return;
    }
    if(head->data == num)
    {
        cur = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete cur;
    }
    else{
        cur = head;
        while(cur!=NULL && cur->data != num)
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur= cur->next;
        }
        if(cur)
        {
            prev->next = cur->next;
            delete cur;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a few questions about this code. First of all, how is it possible to delete a value that was not dynamically allocated? Why is that necessary? I don't see a new statement anywhere. Second of all, why is this block of code necessary? Why does it need to be inside an if statement?

```
if(cur)
        {
            prev->next = cur->next;
            delete cur;
        }
```

Comment: This code in isolation makes no sense, what is head? Is this a method of an object? If so it may have been allocated dynamically elsewhere. Also, this textbook is bad even by the standard of academic coding. Uninitialized variables? Yikes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this code assumes that the nodes were dynamically allocated. That's the way linked lists are usually constructed. If your code uses nodes on the stack, then just remove the `delete` statements. (And give a little thought to how you'll keep track of which nodes are in use.)

Second, that block of code is necessary because it removes the node that is to be removed-- if that node exists. It is in an `if` block in case the node does not exist. Draw up a simple example on paper, and step through the code to see what happens if you try to remove an element that isn't in the list.

Comment: And just to clarify Beta's point, `if(cur)` is the same thing as `if(cur != NULL)`

Comment: @zzxyz: Yes, I should have explained that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, guys, that really clears things up about the if statement. I'll have to admit, though, I am still a bit confused on the issue of deleting things that seemingly have no new statement. I must be missing something.

Comment: Look around in the book for a function called "add" :)  There is almost definitely a new statement somewhere.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code (as a [minimal complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible), we can't tell whether there's a `new` statement or not. To answer your question directly, if the rest of the code uses the function above to remove a node that was *not* created dynamically, then the result will be UB, and the code is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to `delete` a value that wasn't previously allocated with a `new`. I assume `new`-allocation is implied by your textbook.

Regarding your second question, after

```
while(cur!=NULL && cur->data != num){...}
```

has finished, either `cur == NULL` or `cur != NULL && cur->data == num`. `if (cur)` is effectively `if (cur != NULL)` and it implies that `cur` contains the value you were looking for.

The block itself is needed to remove the found element by changing the `next` pointer of the previous element to the element, that goes after the one being removed.